# Write java class using FileWriter and create instance of generated class

Tags: java, gwt, filewriter

I have used file writer to create `xyz.java` file. I have created one map inside it and updating only that map continuously with new values by using file writer.

**xyz.java**

```
Class xyz{
   private HashMap tempMap= new HashMap();

   public HashMap getTypeMap(){
      tempMap.put("Pqr","stu");
   }
 }
```

Newly updated `xyz.java` will update only getTypeMap() method and other parts of the class will remain unchanged.

```
 public HashMap getTypeMap(){
      tempMap.put("Pqr","stu");
      tempMap.put("utr","zyr");

   }
```

I have one helper class through which I am updating `xyz.java` file and inside of that class I'm creating an instance of `xyz` class and accessing map but getting map value is null.

```
 class helper{

          1.// code to update xyz.java file.
          2.// code to create instacne
           xyz obj = new xyz();
           obj.getTypeMap();

        }
```

But if we debugged above code and tried to get map it's giving correct populated map. But if we directly run above code it giving map as null. What can be the reason?

Please assume that above is pseudo code. Don't consider any compilation issues.

Comment: How do you create that instance? What you do is not supported by standard means. Are you compiling the class and replacing it with a custom classloader?

Comment: @zapl no not using any custom classloader.

Comment: Sound like a maximum complex solution for a simple task, just my 2 ct - what is the purpose of all this?

Comment: @GyroGearless actually I am using GWT custom class generator and some part of that each generated class need to store in one class and I want store json of that class in pqr.json  file.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you simply update a json file with the data like `{"Pqr":"stu","utr":"zyr"}` then just reload that file? Dynamic code generation to update some data sounds like the most difficult way I can imagine to achieve that goal.

Comment: @zapl Actually map structure is not that simple its nested map of object .so producing direct json is difficult. Thats why I am creating class with map and creating its json.

Comment: Producing complex nested json isn't difficult, e.g.  http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values - you can also just turn your Map into json via that library with a single line of code.  Complex Json is standard procedure for almost any modern application

Comment: Generating Java classes is best done with annotation processing, and still it's a very complex thing to do. I would not recommend that. 
Use data instead, json works very nicely both in the server and client side.

Comment: When do you expect the file is generated/updated?

Comment: In dev mode it could work because the code server recompiles your `xyz.java`. It just won't work in production mode that way.

Answer (score 0):

getTypeMap() should return something like `public HashMap getTypeMap(){return...}`. currently it is type void.
I noticed that you do not have method getMap() in your xyz.java. Is it a typo? Should it be `obj.getTypeMap()`

```
 class helper{

   1.// code to update xyz.java file.
   2.// code to create instacne
    xyz obj = new xyz();
    HashMap result = obj.getTypeMap();//

 }
Class xyz{
   private HashMap tempMap= new HashMap();

   public HashMap getTypeMap(){
      tempMap.put("Pqr","stu");
      return this. tempMap;
   }
 }
```

Comment: getTypeMap() is type void hence it will not return anything. It should return HashMap `public HashMap getTypeMap() {return this.tempMap} `